# Find intersection points of two circles on sphere (earth)

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

### Problem

Assume that we have two devices that can measure distance to the target. Devices installed on earth at coordinats ***A*** and ***B***. We measure distances ***Da***, ***Db*** in meters.

How to find points of intersection?

### Subproblem

If measurements have some uncertainty in meters. What is the best way to calculate uncertainty of intersection points?

[image: img]

Comment: What is a typical value for distance $AB$? If it is small in comparison with Earth radius then you can safely carry out your calculations as if you were on a plane.

Comment: I have an idea, if we represent Earth as a sphere equation at point ***(0,0,0)***, and intersect it with sphere at point ***A*** with radius ***Da*** we get circle in 3d space, then do the same for point ***B*** and get another circle. Finally add two circle equations and get result.